# CSS wrapping different numbers of columns in a responsive layout with two to three columns

Tags: css, responsive-design, semantics

I'm trying to wrap some column style divs in a row.  Then apply overflow:hidden; to the row to make whatever floated columns are in the next row line up.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col">Column 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col">Column 4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Column 5</div>
    <div class="col">Column 6</div>
</div>
```

Then use:

```
.row{ overflow:hidden; }
.col{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

The problem is, on a larger screen I want to effectively move the row divs so I can show 3 columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col">Column 2</div>
    <div class="col">Column 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Column 4</div>
    <div class="col">Column 5</div>
    <div class="col">Column 6</div>
</div>
```

And use:

```
.row{ overflow:hidden; }
.col{
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
```

Now, I know this can't be done in CSS, but are there any other ways for wrapping columns or getting this effect using CSS which I can use?  The best I've come up with is a rather ugly version using extra elements:

http://codepen.io/djave_co/pen/EIHzt

If you resize the screen you can see its working, but its not very neat or semantic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve something like that? -> **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LwutG**

CSS

```
.clear {clear: both;}

.col{
  border:2px solid #eaeaea;
  min-height:20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}


@media screen and (max-width:1400px) {
        .col {
     width: 33.333333%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
        .col {
     width: 50%;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Set height equal on all cols. **http://jsfiddle.net/C86b8/**

Comment: If you add any content over one line it doesn't work unfortunately http://codepen.io/djave_co/pen/qcBsf

Comment: Are you willing to use a few lines of jQuery? Check out my updated solution