# css to give variable numbers of columns of data for responsive website

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

This isn’t a ‘normal’ data display. I’m reading records from a database (theatre events) and want to display them in nicely lined up rows and columns. A non-responsive, tables-based example is at http://cotswoldplayhouse.co.uk/jm3/index.php/what-s-on

What I want is for the number of columns to go to 2 then 1 as the screen size reduces. I found some hints on how to do that hereabouts such as [CSS wrapping different numbers of columns in a responsive layout with two to three columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584624) and that led to the experiment at http://cotswoldplayhouse.co.uk/jm3/index.php/what-s-on-2
It’s going in the right direction but there are a number of problems.

The first catch seems to be that I need all the cells in a row to be the same size and there is no way to work out which is biggest (and hence size the others) until we know how many are in the row.

The second catch is that the various areas of each event need to line up e.g. the top of each image should be level.  … but we don’t know how deep the image – or the text – is going to be.

I fixed this in the tables version by building a row of 4 at a time with separate rows for title, picture, etc. That works well but can’t (as far as I know) be made responsive.
If I knew the screen size, I could deliver the right number of columns via php but, of course, that won’t work as media queries are client side and php isn’t!

(The whole lot gets wrapped up into a Joomla page but I don't think that creates any extra problems.)

To sum up, I’m stuck! Any suggestions would be gratefully received.
Steve

---

**Code snippet:** (this is an approximation, because all the code is PHP generated)

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  var col_height=0;
  var col_elem;

  $('.col').each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.outerHeight() > col_height ) {
      col_elem=this;
      col_height=$this.outerHeight();
    }
  });

  $('.col').height(col_height);
});
```

```css
.clear {clear: both;}

.col{
  border:1px dashed;
  min-height:20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}


@media screen and (min-width:480px) {
  .col {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width:880px) {
  .col {
    width: 25%;
  }
}


table.whatson {
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
  border: none;

}

table.whatson td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 220px;
  color:#000000;
  position:relative;

}

.whatson-title  {
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
} 
.whatson-dates  {
  font-weight: bold;
} 

tr.sg-link-row {
  height: 50px;
}

div.sg-read-more {
  position:absolute;  
  left:15px;
  bottom:2px; 
}

div.sg-read-more a{
  display:block;
  background:url(images/read-more.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
  width:80px;
  height:40px;
  text-indent:-9999px;
}   

div.sg-read-more a:hover {
  background-position:0 -40px;
} 

div.sg-book-ticket {
  position:absolute;  
  right:15px;
  bottom:2px; 
}

div.sg-book-ticket a{
  display:block;
  background:url(images/buy-ticket.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
  width:80px;
  height:40px;
  text-indent:-9999px;
}   

div.sg-book-ticket a:hover {
  background-position:0 -40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='col'>
  <table class='whatson'><tr><td><p class='whatson-title'>Blighty Bound</p></td></tr><tr>
    <td>Picture Placeholder</td></tr><tr>
    <td><p class='whatson-dates'>26th to 29th November 2014 at 7.30 pm.</p></td></tr><tr>
    <td><p class='whatson-company'>Cotswold Players</p></td>

    </tr><tr class='sg-link-row'>
    <td><div class='sg-read-more'>Find out more placeholder</div>
    </tr></table>
</div>

<div class='col'>
  <table class='whatson'><tr><td><p class='whatson-title'>Cinderella</p></td></tr><tr>
    <td>Picture Placeholder</td></tr><tr>
    <td><p class='whatson-dates'>21st to 24th and 28th to 31st January 2015 at 7.30 pm. (2.30 pm matinees on both Saturdays)</p></td></tr><tr>
    <td><p class='whatson-company'>Cotswold Players</p></td>

    </tr><tr class='sg-link-row'>
    <td><div class='sg-read-more'>Find out more placeholder</div>
    </tr></table>
</div>

<div class='col'>
  <table class='whatson'><tr><td><p class='whatson-title'>The Autumn of Han</p></td></tr><tr>
    <td>Picture Placeholder</td></tr><tr>
    <td><p class='whatson-dates'>6th February 2015</p></td></tr><tr>
    <td><p class='whatson-company'>Red Dragonfly Productions</p></td>

    </tr><tr class='sg-link-row'>
    <td><div class='sg-read-more'>Find out more placeholder</div>
    </tr></table>
</div>

<div class='col'>
  <table class='whatson'><tr><td><p class='whatson-title'>The Bronte Season - Jane Eyre</p></td></tr><tr>
    <td>Picture Placeholder</td></tr><tr>
    <td><p class='whatson-dates'>11th February at 7.30 pm</p></td></tr><tr>
    <td><p class='whatson-company'>Live Wire Theatre</p></td>

    </tr><tr class='sg-link-row'>
    <td><div class='sg-read-more'>Find out more placeholder</div>
    </tr></table>
</div>

<div class='col'>
  <table class='whatson'><tr><td><p class='whatson-title'>The Bronte Season - Wuthering Heights</p></td></tr><tr>
    <td>Picture Placeholder</td></tr><tr>
    <td><p class='whatson-dates'>13th February at 7.30 pm</p></td></tr><tr>
    <td><p class='whatson-company'>Live Wire Theatre</p></td>

    </tr><tr class='sg-link-row'>
    <td><div class='sg-read-more'>Find out more placeholder</div>
    </tr></table>
</div>

<div class='col'>
  <table class='whatson'><tr><td><p class='whatson-title'>The Bronte Season - The Tenant of Wildfell Hall</p></td></tr><tr>
    <td>Picture Placeholder</td></tr><tr>
    <td><p class='whatson-dates'>13th February at 7.30 pm</p></td></tr><tr>
    <td><p class='whatson-company'>Live Wire Theatre</p></td>

    </tr><tr class='sg-link-row'>
    <td><div class='sg-read-more'>Find out more placeholder</div>
    </tr></table>
</div>


<div class='clear'></div>
```

(**jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sclg/xeoqukab/1/**)

Comment: Your question is well stated, but the solution will require being hands on with the code. Post a codepen/jsfiddle with your latest code, you'll get help much more readily.

Comment: Sorry to be negative but you're using a table for layout which is bad practice. Responsive design using tables for layout is pretty much impossible unfortunately. The best thing to do is redesign using a grid system (such as simple grid) which alread has the functionality that you're looking for built in.

Comment: http://thisisdallas.github.io/Simple-Grid/

Comment: Shawn - Took a while because all the code is php generated but this is an approximation - http://jsfiddle.net/sclg/xeoqukab/1/

Comment: Pat - I know tables are not the way to go - that's why I'm asking :-)
I've used a number of Grid systems (and Joomla has Bootstrap built in) but I still can't find a solution to this problem...